# SSL for company internal Intranet (.NET Core Razor)

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome, active-directory, ssl-certificate, intranet

I set up a local Intranet site for our company on a new web server running IIS 10. I did this using .NET Core Razor pages where I get the logged on Windows user and grant/deny access based on their User ID being in specific Active Directory groups via SQL ADSI queries.

I issued a self-signed certificate which was working just fine until the recent Chrome update which no longer accepts my self-signed cert. The cert still works in Edge. Most of what I find for Chrome is a work-around telling people to just type, "thisisunsafe", which works but is not a valid solution.
The only other info I can find is advice to get the 3rd party SSL cert, even though all of this is behind our firewall. I did this, and that's not working either.

I don't understand why I can't use a self-signed cert for my own internal site. What is the best practice to manage the security for an Internal company intranet and the cert process needed?

Comment: *"get the 3rd party SSL cert, even though all of this is behind our firewall. I did this, and that's not working either"* - This should work. What is not working?

Comment: Within your own domain, you can set up AD CS to issue your own certificates, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831740(v=ws.11) I assume this is the essential knowledge of a domain administrator and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: "This should work. What is not working?" DigiCert said it's because they can't authenticate behind our firewall after taking our money for the cert. Chrome won't let me self sign my cert, and 3rd party certs won't authenticate behind a firewall, so how do companies implement SSL on their Intranet?
I'm looking into setting up an AD CS for now.